# is it possible to add a button in the mui date calendar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

I want to add button in the mui date calendar header section. Will it be possible ?
[Demo project link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wind-mqtp85?file=/src/CustomDateCalendar.js).
See the picture for more clarification

[image: date calendar]